# Unable to obtain origin of NSLog in a Parse block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am using the following code to log in a user to my application using parse.com

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:usernameString password:passwordString
                                    block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                        if (user) {
                                            // Do stuff after successful login.
                                            NSLog(@"The user has logged in");
                                        } else {
                                            // The login failed. Check error to see why.


                                        }
                                    }];
```

The code works great and is documented on the Parse.com API Documentation [HERE](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/logInWithUsernameInBackground:password:block:)

My problem however is that I want to be able to show an alert to users when their login credentials come back with with an error, currently I get the following error on my console when I try to sign in with invalid credentials: `Error: invalid login credentials (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.19)`

Thats great, but I have looked everywhere and cant seem to find where that code, is being created... I am looking for it so that I can add different error messages for to my users: i.e.

```
  if ([errorString rangeOfString:@"username"].location == NSNotFound) {


                      //the issue is not username related
                        } else
{
NSLog= (@"The username has been taken");
}
```

Any idea how I can find the string that contains the error and examine it so that I may act accordingly to the error?

Comment: Why aren't you just checking the `NSError` object ?

Comment: @Paulw11 when I check the NSError object with an `NSLog` but I get the following `Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 101.)" UserInfo=0x10a24a2b0 {error=invalid login credentials, code=101}` when really, all I want is the string that contains "`invalid login credentials`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the parse error codes are all documented here:
https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFConstants.html

101 is kPFErrorObjectNotFound
and means 'Object doesn't exist, or has an incorrect password.'

during a login it is likely more the later ;)

so:

```
 if(error.code == kPFErrorObjectNotFound) {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"parse login error" message:@"Invalid credentials" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"];
      [alert show];
 }
```

---

## dont use the error string of an NSError as you can't really tell if it is suitable for display.

still it is likely in `localizedDescription` or some other `userInfo` field

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for [`NSError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSError/userInfo) you will see that its `userInfo` property is a dictionary.  From your NSLog you can see that the `error` key contains the string you are after, so you can access it with

```
NSString *errorMessage=[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"];
```

Although, rather than parsing strings it is safer to check the `error.code` value for 101, possibly displaying the error message for more detail.  Checking the error code rather than the string will ensure that a change in the string by Parse won't break your code